# from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-import, manage.py

I am working on a bug project. Which is on Python 2.7, we are migrating to Python 3.9. I am getting import errors in manage.py during import`from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line`.
For python 2.7 it is fine but for python 3 it is not working.
I've created separate virtual environment for Python 3.

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "best_buy_mall.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

dir tree:
my_app/django_site/manage.py

my_app/venv (for python2)

my_app/v_env (for python3)

Comment: Can you please provide the exception description? Have you installed django on the new environment? Can you please check and send `pip list` from the new python3 env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo pip install django --upgrade
```

I solved this by upgrading django.
and if someone getting psycopg2 error, then run

```
sudo pip install psycopg2 --upgrade
```

or install psycopg-binary

```
sudo pip install psycopg2-binary --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.